# Querying and sorting indexed collection in MongoDB results in data overflow

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

"events" is a capped collection that stores user click events on a webpage. A document looks like this:

```
{
    "event_name" : "click",
    "user_id" : "ea0b4027-05f7-4902-b133-ff810b5800e1",
    "object_type" : "ad",
    "object_id" : "ea0b4027-05f7-4902-b133-ff810b5822e5",
    "object_properties" : { "foo" : "bar" },
    "event_properties" : {"foo" : "bar" },
    "time" : ISODate("2014-05-31T22:00:43.681Z")
}
```

Here's a compound index for this collection:

```
db.events.ensureIndex({object_type: 1, time: 1});
```

This is how I am querying:

```
db.events.find( {
   $or : [ {object_type : 'ad'}, {object_type : 'element'} ],
   time: { $gte: new Date("2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z"), $lte: new Date("2014-09-01T00:00:00.000Z") }}, 
  { user_id: 1, event_name: 1, object_id: 1,  object_type : 1,  obj_properties : 1, time:1 } )
.sort({time: 1});
```

This is causing:  *"too much data for sort() with no index. add an index or specify a smaller limit"* in mongo 2.4.9 and *"Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 33554618 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes"* in Mongo 2.6.3. I'm using Java MongoDB driver 2.12.3. It throws the same error when I use "$natural" sorting. It seems like MongoDB is not really using the index defined for sorting, but I can't figure out why (I read MongoDB documentation on indexes). I appreciate any hints.

Here is the result of **explain()**:

```
{
    "clauses" : [
        {
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor object_type_1_time_1",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "n" : 0,
            "nscannedObjects" : 0,
            "nscanned" : 0,
            "scanAndOrder" : false,
            "indexOnly" : false,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
            "indexBounds" : {
                "object_type" : [
                    [
                        "element",
                        "element"
                    ]
                ],
                "time" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor object_type_1_time_1",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "n" : 399609,
            "nscannedObjects" : 399609,
            "nscanned" : 399609,
            "scanAndOrder" : false,
            "indexOnly" : false,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
            "indexBounds" : {
                "object_type" : [
                    [
                        "ad",
                        "ad"
                    ]
                ],
                "time" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
    "cursor" : "QueryOptimizerCursor",
    "n" : 408440,
    "nscannedObjects" : 409686,
    "nscanned" : 409686,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 409686,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 409686,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "nYields" : 6402,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 2633,
    "server" : "MacBook-Pro.local:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an index for time solely, e.g. not a compound index?

Comment: Yes I did create an index for each, "time" and "object_type", same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to explain(), When the mongo run the query it did use the compound index. The problem is the sort({time:1}). 
Your index is {object_type:1, time:1}, it means the query results are ordered by object_type first, if the object_type is same, then ordered by time.

For the sort {time:1}, mongo have to load all the matched objects(399609) into the memory to sort by time due to the order is not the same to the index({object_type:1, time:1}). Assume that the avg size of object is 100 bytes, then the limit would be exceeded.

more info: **http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/**

For instance, there are 3 objects with index {obj_type:1, time:1}:

```
{"obj_type": "a", "time" : ISODate("2014-01-31T22:00:43.681Z")}
{"obj_type": "c", "time" : ISODate("2014-02-31T22:00:43.681Z")}
{"obj_type": "b", "time" : ISODate("2014-03-31T22:00:43.681Z")}
```

db.events.find({}).sort({"obj_type":1, "time":1}).limit(2)

```
{"obj_type": "a", "time" : ISODate("2014-01-31T22:00:43.681Z")}
{"obj_type": "b", "time" : ISODate("2014-03-31T22:00:43.681Z")}

"nscanned" : 2  (This one use index order, which is sorted by {obj_type:1, time:1})
```

db.events.find({}).sort({"time":1}).limit(2)

```
{"obj_type": "a", "time" : ISODate("2014-01-31T22:00:43.681Z")}
{"obj_type": "c", "time" : ISODate("2014-02-31T22:00:43.681Z")}

"nscanned" : 3 (This one will load all the matched results and then sort)
```

Comment: I realized that the Java Mongo driver connection was still open when I created the indexes using the terminal and this caused the problem above (indeed I had an index for "time"). Thanks for the nice explanation, I'll mark it as accepted.